# merge pdf and send as email php

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to merge three pdf filese with PDFMerger and then send the merged pdf with PHPmailer without saving the file to the server.

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

use PDFMerger\PDFMerger;
require_once 'PDFMerger.php';

$email = new PHPMailer();
$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/one.pdf', 'all');
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/two.pdf', 'all');
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all');

$pdf->merge('string'); // generate the file

$email->SetFrom('kasserer@lst-beboerforening.dk'); //Name is optional
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = 'text to send!';
$email->AddAddress( 'krestensb@gmail.com' );

$email->addAttachment($pdf);

return $email->Send();

?>
```

I get this error:

```
[19-Jan-2020 17:11:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/lstbeboer/public_html/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php on line 1736
[19-Jan-2020 17:11:55 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception' not found in /home/lstbeboer/public_html/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php:2953
Stack trace:
#0 /home/lstbeboer/public_html/PDFMerger-master/sample.php(38): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->addAttachment(Object(PDFMerger\PDFMerger))
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/lstbeboer/public_html/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php on line 2953
```

Any help is very appreciated!

BR Kresten

Comment: Think you will need to `$pdf->merge('file', 'some-dir/some.pdf');` and then you will have a file to attach to the email, but I am not an expert, I just read the documentation

Comment: And then `$email->addAttachment('some-dir/some.pdf');` so you are passing a string identifying a file that exists and not an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `merge()` method in `string` mode should return a binary PDF as a string, so you need to grab the return value:

```
$pdfdata = $pdf->merge('string');
```

Because this data is in a variable and not a file on disk, you can pass it straight to PHPMailer via [the `addStringAttachment()` method](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment):

```
$email->addStringAttachment($pdfdata, 'document.pdf');
```

Giving it a filename is enough to have PHPMailer set the encoding and MIME type automatically.